# Regex for a text field validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I am using **JqueryValidationEngine** to validate my forms on the client side.

I want to validate a text field using regex in a form. The condition is as follows

**Edit:**

**Condition1:**

```
It should not allow the user to enter single or multiple combinations of zeroes.

E.g. '0', '00,, '00000' etc.
```

**Condition2:**

```
It should not allow the user to enter the any multiple digit number starting with 0, but excluding the condition1. 

E.g. '01', '001, '001001' , '000001' etc.
```

I'm using [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) for checking the regex and I need two regex for not allowing the  above two type of values. Thanks :)-

Comment: the question needs to be updated if you are still looking for an answer , as it is probably not clear what conditions you need exactly.

Comment: If any one do want to close this question, please put a comment so that I can understand what is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition 1 (updated according to OP's suggestion)

```
/^[1-9]\d*$/
```

Condition 2 (only digits with first 0 and atleast one non zero)

```
/^0+[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

Inverse of above

```
/^((?!^0+[1-9][0-9]*$).)*$/
```

Comment: actually using Jqueryvalidationengine, the regex we specify to validate e.g. /^0+[1-9][0-9]*$/, this will allow the values '001', '0010' etc. to be entered in the field. I want this to be not allowed for the user while entering

Comment: use this regex and if the condition matches return an error. Sthing like `if input =~ regex then not valid`

Comment: Just check the exp in rubular.com. I can't check it with an If-else condition. Just I would be allowed to specify a regex to which the entry will be validated and will allow the values matching to the regex. So I do not want the values mentioned in the question to be entered

Comment: Have any suggestions?

Comment: updated , but I am not sure about nondigits as the inverse expression would match those.

Comment: ^((?!0+).)*$ will not pass 0, 000 etc. good. but it also not passes 10, 101 etc

Comment: try now...forgot to add `^$` around the negative regex

Comment: Your new condition 1 is actually condition 2.

Answer (score 0):

Condition 1:

```
^\d*[1-9]\d*$
```

Condition 2:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

Comment: regex is written to avoid such patterns from occurring. I hope the above is for allowing them to pass through

Comment: I am not sure what your comment means. The expressions match if your conditions occur.

Comment: Thought you only wanted binary numbers, fixed condition 2.

Comment: I guess the latest edit is what you wanted.

Comment: Is something wrong with my solution?

Comment: yes, please refer to the third comment to tihom. Thanks for the help

Comment: That is what the expressions are doing.

Comment: Your second condition is ok. But using the first one, it is also validating the second condition. I want them seperately

Answer (score -1):

```
if exp =~ /^[0]+/
  'message 1'
elsif exp =~ /^0[01]*/ 
  'message 2'
end
```